# How to hyperlink CSS-made images?

Tags: html, css

I understand if this question's title sounds noobish, but I've been learning a little bit of HTML // CSS for a little while now!

I'm trying to hyperlink the images themselves while still retaining their ability to change on hover, but I can't figure out how. What I'm doing currently is using text set to transparent to make the buttons link to where I want to go because I cannot link the images themselves.

[Here's a page with the current code I use for the buttons](http://utbuttons.tumblr.com/).

This codes...

```
<style type="text/css">
...
.apple1 {
    width:110px;
    height:42px;
    background:transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/DpHlf33.png);
}

.apple1:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/5NsAhep.png);
}

.apple2 {
    width:110px;
    height:42px;
    background:transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/P6TS6ik.png);
}
.apple2:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/58NhKNy.png);
}

.apple3 {
    width:110px;
    height:42px;
    background:transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/5engqoR.png);
}
.apple3:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/sA4YYsN.png);
}

.apple4 {
    width:110px;
    height:42px;
    background:transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/F3iqugS.png);
}
.apple4:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/DDUJvGp.png);
}

.apple a {
    font-size:42px;
    color:transparent;
}
</style>

<body>
...
<div class="apple">
<div class="apple1"><a href="http://the-tutoriel.tumblr.com/check" title="* Check">Chec</a></div><br>
<div class="apple2"><a href="{text:Link 2 url}" title="{text:Link 2}">Talk</a></div><br>
<div class="apple3"><a href="{text:Link 3 url}" title="{text:Link 3}">Item</a></div><br>
<div class="apple4"><a href="/" title="* Spare">Spar</a></div><br>
</div>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple techniques of text-to-image replacement. One of most reliable while accessible ways is adding `overflow: hidden`, setting a dimension (`width` or `height`) to `0`, and setting `padding` to the needed value of the zeroed dimension:

```css
.example {
    background: url(example.png) no-repeat;
    display: block; /* for inline elements like A */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 42px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: To my brain, your response was a tad vague, so the only result I got ended up being [this](http://i.imgur.com/DdXuSfa.png). Even adjusting the padding didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure what is tad vague. You should of course set both dimensions, and only one should be replaced with padding. So based on your screenshot, the Check button would have `overflow: hidden; padding-top: 42px; width: 110px; height: 0;`. I use this method for over 10 years. ;-)

Comment: It worked, thank you! The only issue I had with this new code was the text wasn't big enough to make the entire image "linked", but all I had to do was increase the font size.

Also, when I said vague, I was referring to not knowing which class to put the code under, but in retrospect it was kind of obvious. :)

Comment: @StevenUniverse You need to close this thread thanks :)

Comment: @StevenUniverse You should of course make inline element `block` or `inline-block`. I've updated the code example.